# R dplyr mutate multiple columns using custom function to create new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to create new column in data.frame using `dplyr::mutate` using custom function which argument is vector of data.frame's column names but I got following output:

```
customFun <- function(col.vec) {
  paste0(gsub("\\s", "_", col.vec), collapse = "-")
}

df <- data.frame(A = c("x 1", "x", "x w"), B = c("E", "D", "2 w"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
   mutate(C = customFun(c(A, B)))
    A   B                 C
1 x 1   E x_1-x-x_w-E-D-2_w
2   x   D x_1-x-x_w-E-D-2_w
3 x w 2 w x_1-x-x_w-E-D-2_w
```

instead of:

```
data.table::data.table(df)[, C := customFun(c(A, B)), by = .(A, B)]
     A   B       C
1: x 1   E   x_1-E
2:   x   D     x-D
3: x w 2 w x_w-2_w
```

It can be achieved in many ways, but I'm interested in `dplyr` solution only. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mutate can only give back a vector that is the same length as the data or just with length one. So far your custom function does not do that. I guess you are not doing what you expect to be doing eg, what are you pasting exactly? you have one long vector, what are you pasting it to using the sep?? try `with(head(iris),customFun(c(Species, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)))` and you will see that its not what you want. `c(Species, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)` is already a vector so tecnically cannot be pasted with another thing that does not exist

Comment: Sorry guys, I provided bad example - I updated my question and it's ok now.

Comment: Even wen using data.tables, if you have two similar rows, thy will be collapsed itnto one. Youe customFunc is not right

Comment: You need to do something like `df%>%mutate(C = invoke(paste,data.frame(gsub('\\s+','_',as.matrix(.))),sep='-'))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map` and `lift_dl`. We first `map` over each `col.vec` (notice I have used a list instead of a vector as input, since `c` flattens any vector elements, while list doesn't) and apply `gsub`. Then the list output is fed into `paste`. Since `paste` takes `...`, we can use `purrr::lift_dl` to lift it's input domain from `...` to `list` type:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

customFun <- function(col.vec) {
  map(col.vec, ~gsub("\\s", "_", .x)) %>%
    lift_dl(paste, sep = "-")()
}

df %>%
  mutate(C = customFun(list(A, B)))
```

or with `...` as input:

```
customFun <- function(...) {
  col.vec <- list(...)
  map(col.vec, ~gsub("\\s", "_", .x)) %>%
    lift_dl(paste, sep = "-")()
}

df %>%
  mutate(C = customFun(A, B))
```

**Output:**

```
    A   B       C
1 x 1   E   x_1-E
2   x   D     x-D
3 x w 2 w x_w-2_w
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `rowwise` before your `mutate` so only *each* row's A & B values are used in `paste`, rather than the vectors of *all* rows.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C = customFun(c(A, B)))
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   A     B     C      
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 x 1   E     x_1-E  
#> 2 x     D     x-D    
#> 3 x w   2 w   x_w-2_w
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Why use `by=.(..)` in your `data.table` solution? If at all you have two rows with exactly similar values, then these will be collapsed into one. You need to modify your `customFun`. It is not correct the way it is:

```
library(tidyverse)
customFun = function(data) invoke(paste, data.frame(gsub('\\s+', '_', as.matrix(data))), sep='-')

df %>% 
    mutate(c = customFun(.))

    A   B       C
1 x 1   E   x_1-E
2   x   D     x-D
3 x w 2 w x_w-2_w
```

You can replace the invoke with `do.call` or even `lift` etc.

Your function is not doing exactly what you want. Read the comment above